# XAML Bindings not working in custom EventTriggers

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, eventtrigger

Hey all, I am having this really annoying problem... I have the following EventTrigger below:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;

namespace App.Common.Actions
{
    public class SoundEffectAction : TriggerAction<FrameworkElement>
    {
        [Category("Sound Effect")]
        public string Source
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
        } 

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(string), typeof(SoundEffectAction), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty)); 

        protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Source))
            {
                var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream(this.Source);
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
                    FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
                    effect.Play();
                }
            }
        } 
     }
}
```

This all compiles and runs perfectly fine EXCEPT for when I try to bind to it in a DataTemplate...

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Margin="10" Height="75" Width="75" >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown" SourceName="stackPanel">
                <action:SoundEffectAction Source="{Binding SoundPath}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>                                   
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

When I try to run this, I run into problems... Visual Studio says:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  Message=AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE [Line: 4 Position: 43]
  LineNumber=4
  LinePosition=43
  StackTrace:
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureChild(UIElement child, Size layoutSlotSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureOverrideNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureOverrideNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureOverrideNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives.PanoramaPanel.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureOverrideNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureOverrideNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
       at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Panorama.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureOverrideNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureOverrideNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
       at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationFrame.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
```

So that's not really fun at all.... Any ideas would be greatly appreciated :)

Jourdan

Answer (score 1):

Is this part correct?

```
<action:SoundEffectAction Source="{SoundPath}"/>
```

Shouldn't that be "{Binding SoundPath}" or something else?

Comment: Sorry yes you are right, that was a typo on my part! Will edit OP :)

Answer (score 0):

Where have you declared "SoundPath"?

If it is a DependencyProperty, the you should use:

```
<action:SoundEffectAction Source="{Binding Path=SoundPath, ElementName=your_element_name}"/>
```

If it is declared as a resource:

```
<action:SoundEffectAction Source="{StaticResource your_resource_key}"/>
```